# Saving user input as a variable in c# on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm creating a very simple windows phone app. I'm browsing through msdn help files and making it. I would like to save what a user types into a textbox as a variable. How can that be achived? Also, how can I make the user only able to type numbers(numeric values) not letters into the text box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just google it, for example 'msdn textbox windows phone', you can find much to do it yourself.

For input with only digit, use [input scope](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/10/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-10-inputscope-textboxes/) with [Digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

For save input as a variable use [TextChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or query value as `string value = textBox1.Text`

Answer (score 1):

> text Variable = int.Parse(Your Variable That Text Is Being Saved Too);

Answer (score 0):

For the second question use Input Spoce for the TextBox like this

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" Name="input1" ></TextBox>
```

To save the the users input, you have to name your TextBox and then simply save the `input1.Text` property. If you wanna save it so the next time your app starts the user can recover it, then use `IsolatedStorageSettings` to save it.